# URLClassLoader can't find classes

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I want to use an URLClassLoader to load classes in a particular directory from a jar-archive.

The project structure is as follows

```
/
 application.jar
 /lib/
  mysql.jar
  log4j.jar
  ...
 /myClasses/
  class1.class
  class2.class
  ...
```

The jar has the following manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b10 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: de.application.start
Class-Path: lib/mysql.jar lib/log4j.jar lib/....jar
```

What I do currently is iterating over all files within `/myClasses/` and trying to load that particular class (they all have the same package) like this:

```
File classDir = new File("/path/to/my/root/folder/myClasses/");
URL[] url = { classdir.toURI().toURL() };
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url);
for (File file : classDir.listFiles()) {
    String filename = StringUtil.getFilenameWithoutExtension(file.getName());
    loader.loadClass("de.myClasses." + filename).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

But, even though the files obviously exist, I always get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.myClasses.class1` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You write tjat you want to load classes from jar archive, but in your code you give raw directory ("/path/to/my/root/folder/myClasses/") as a parameter to URLClassLoader. You must specify jar file here.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My application resides in a jar archive and out of that archive I want to load other classes in a directory

Comment: Is your goal to access a class that's stored within a jar that's stored within a jar? That doesn't work, and I'm sure that a search will turn up lots of posts that tell you why and how to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your compiled classes in directories according its packages.
So class `de.myClasses.Class1` should be in directory `/myClasses/de/myClasses/`.

Answer (score 1):

`file.getName()` returns `"Class1.class"` instead of `"Class1"`, right? remove last 6 chars.

Also, if Class1 is in package `de.myClasses` it should be at

```
<your_base_dir>/de/myClasses
```

and if Class1 is in top package (no package) then you should ask for it as

```
loader.loadClass("Class1") // no de.mClasses. prefix
```

Comment: No, I have done that in my application. I wrote it here this way to save space, I will change it.